# YouTube Direct Lite "Playlist" parameter is missing

Tags: parameters, youtube, playlist

I have set up YouTube Direct Lite on my site. Got the Auth working, able to log in via YouTube  using your Google account. Now the problem arises when I load the page.

I get an error that states "The "Playlist" URL parameter is missing". I have been trying to solve this problem all day. I assume its something with the global variable that gets the playlist id.

I can't tell how the variable is being called or stored, so I don't know if it's a problem with that.

```
 if (panel.needsPlaylist && !globals.hashParams.playlist) {
          utils.showMessage('The "playlist" URL parameter is missing.');
          return;
        }
```

That is the line of code returning the error, but I can't find anywhere in the code where globals.hashParams.playlist is being stored.

Any one else encountered and got around the problem??

This is happening on all three tabs as they all require this "playlist". Extremely frustrating....as it mentions nothing of this in the api documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to the "admin" section of the app, click on the playlist you want to embed to, then you'll get the embed code "To add a submission widget associated with this playlist, use the following HTML code:".

Paste that iframe in and you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

using the iframe from admin just loads the hosted version of it.

Amir's answer is the closest you will get since they refuse to allow my other answer with the final solution. good Luck.

Login to the "admin" section of the app, click on the playlist you want to embed to, then you'll get the embed code "To add a submission widget associated with this playlist, use the following HTML code:".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).