# Getting "The "Playlist" URL parameter is missing" when using the YouTube Direct Lite code

Tags: youtube-api

I have set up YouTube Direct Lite on my site. Got the Auth working, able to log in via YouTube using your Google account. Now the problem arises when I load the page.

I get an error that states "The "Playlist" URL parameter is missing". I have been trying to solve this problem all day. I assume its something with the global variable that gets the playlist id.

I can't tell how the variable is being called or stored, so I don't know if it's a problem with that.

```
if (panel.needsPlaylist && !globals.hashParams.playlist) {
              utils.showMessage('The "playlist" URL parameter is missing.');
              return;
            }
```

That is the line of code returning the error, but I can't find anywhere in the code where globals.hashParams.playlist is being stored.

Any one else encountered and got around the problem??

This is happening on all three tabs as they all require this "playlist". Extremely frustrating....as it mentions nothing of this in the api documentation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [YouTube Direct Lite "Playlist" parameter is missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423457/youtube-direct-lite-playlist-parameter-is-missing)

Comment: but the answer in YouTube Direct Lite "Playlist" parameter is missing  is incorrect

Comment: May be related to https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/issues/detail?id=37.